# How is String class in Kotlin Standard library implemented?

Tags: java, kotlin

File can be found here - https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/core/builtins/native/kotlin/String.kt

Adding String.kt code for reference

```
package kotlin

/**
* The `String` class represents character strings. All string literals in 
* Kotlin programs, such as `"abc"`, are
* implemented as instances of this class.
*/

public class String : Comparable<String>, CharSequence {
companion object {}

/**
 * Returns a string obtained by concatenating this string with the string representation of the given [other] object.
 */
public operator fun plus(other: Any?): String

public override val length: Int

/**
 * Returns the character of this string at the specified [index].
 *
 * If the [index] is out of bounds of this string, throws an [IndexOutOfBoundsException] except in Kotlin/JS
 * where the behavior is unspecified.
 */
public override fun get(index: Int): Char

public override fun subSequence(startIndex: Int, endIndex: Int): CharSequence

public override fun compareTo(other: String): Int
}
```

I want to understand how the methods shown doesn't have any implementation? Also please brief on how this code could possibly work?

If there is native code being used. Please link the source code of the same..

Comment: Please share code as formatted text, not picture.

Comment: @Zabuza I have linked to the file below the image.

Comment: String is compiled through compiler magic as a Java String on the JDK, so you can look at that source code to see how it works. http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java

Comment: @Tenfour04 ok, in the library where is it actually happening? the linking of Kotlin String to Java String class. Also If you see in the same kotlin package, there is Array class. How is it getting mapped to Java array?

Comment: @abitcode I know you linked it, but it would increase your audience and responses if you share it directly, also increases up-votes. And it makes the question self-contained in case the external resource becomes unavailable. See [ask], thanks.

Comment: You also linked to the Kotlin/Native version, not Kotlin/JVM.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Can you share the Kotlin/JVM source link, I couldn't find it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kotlin's standard library is shared between all the platforms supported by Kotlin, so it contains only signatures of methods. Several classes are implemented identically to platform-specific ones: for example, in Kotlin/JVM `kotlin.text.StringBuilder` is implemented as a type-alias to `java.lang.StringBuilder`.

However, some types are mapped by the compiler specifically to platform types (some methods are removed, some methods are renamed). These types include primitive types (Int, Byte, etc.), String and collections.

As for JVM the rough mapping is:

```
kotlin.String.length => java.lang.String.length()
kotlin.String.compareTo(other: String) => java.lang.String.compareTo(java.langString anotherString)
kotlin.String.get(index: Int) => java.lang.String.charAt(int index)
kotlin.String.plus(other: Any?) is implemented as plain Java concatentation (it is implemented on compiler level with StringConcatFactory magic)
kotlin.String.subSequence(startIndex: Int, endIndex: Int) => java.lang.String.subSequence(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
```

Other `java.lang.String` methods like `intern` are not available in `kotlin.String` (however, it is actually possible to reference `java.lang.String` directly).

In Kotlin/Native `kotlin.String` is implemented with C++: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/045b20a36b8a1fe86716a99cb25f03021e583592/runtime/src/main/cpp/KString.cpp.

JavaScript implementation involves builtin JavaScript String too.